# Get ItemId from document URL using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a document URL of a document saved in Office 365. I would like to retrieve the ItemID of the document using Graph API. How do I do that using Graph API?

Comment: Could you show an example of the document URL that is saved in Office365?  I suspect you may be able to take part of the path to the document, and retrieve the driveItem for that file which will contain the itemId.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution to the question https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0